# Migrating from CCL to V3: How do I get a list of cast devices and how do I initiate a connect to one of them?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm migrating from CCL to V3 and I can't find a way to get a list of cast devices.

I can not use the connect dialog provided by the Cast SDK as my own connect dialog provides a lot of other options, help messages, etc. My own connect dialog has gone through its own evolution based on user feedback and other factors for several years.

So how can I populate it with a list of cast devices using V3 of the api?

Thanks.

Comment: You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/ccl_migrate_sender). Be noted that if you're migrating to v3, you should be using `CastContext` and not `GoogleAPIClient` for accessing the Cast API. It is proper to use `GoogleAPIClient` for accessing other Google Play services APIs.

Comment: For [Device Discovery](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/ccl_migrate_sender#device_discovery), in v3, the discovery process is started and stopped automatically by the framework when the app comes to the foreground and goes to the background, respectively. For [Cast Dialog](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/ccl_migrate_sender#cast_button_and_cast_dialog), instead of using `CastManager.addMediaRouterButton`, use v3's `CastButtonFactory` to wire up the `MediaRouteButton` to the Cast framework.

Comment: But I want to use my own button and my own dialog.